# Fetching Facebook user data using fbsdk 4.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a beginner in iOS development. I searched a lot but didn't get my code working cause of some deprecated class in latest fbsdk 4.2. What i want is that integration of fb in my apps. I am Able to integrate fb in my app and i can successfully login and logout. Now my app need is to fetch the logged-in user e-mail id and display it in a label. Here is my code, which i have tried.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];



    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                  parameters:@{@"fields":@"email"}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        if(!error)
        {
            self.lblEmail.text = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
            NSLog(@"email:%@", result);
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working fine with me for facebook sdk 4.2

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error)
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
            else
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.